# Baby rudin exercise 2.7

Tags: real-analysis

According to Baby rudin exercise 2.7,

When $A_n,n\in N$ is subset of metric space and, If $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=B$ ,then $\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}\subseteq\bar{B}$, $(\bar{a}$ is closure of $a)$.

However, the reverse containment $\bar{B}\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}$ does not necessarily hold.

because, let $A_i=\{r_i\},r_i\in \mathbb{Q}$, because rational number is countable $B=\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ can be $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\bar{B}=\mathbb{R}$
but $\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}=\mathbb{Q}$.therefore  $\bar{B}\nsubseteq\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}$ for some case.

Here is my question, I try to prove $\bar{B}\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}$ in this way,

$$x\in \bar{B}\Rightarrow x \in B \lor x\in B' $$
$$x\in B\Rightarrow x\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}$$
$$x\in B'\Rightarrow \forall r>0,N_r(x)\cap B\neq \emptyset$$
$$\Rightarrow N_r(x)\cap \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\neq \emptyset$$
$$\Rightarrow \exists i\in \mathbb{N}\ s.t\ N_r(x)\cap A_i\neq \emptyset $$ 
$$\Rightarrow \exists i\in \mathbb{N}\ s.t\ x\in \bar{A_i}$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in \cup_{n=1}^\infty\bar{A_i}$$
Therefore $\bar{B} \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}$

What is problem in my proof?

Comment: What is $B'$? ${}{}$

Comment: The short answer is that you’ve fixed $r$ in the $4$th line. So there exists an $i$ for that $r$, but that $i$ does not work for every $r$. This is contrary to what you assert when you go from the $5$th to the $6$th line.

Comment: Apologies if that was unclear. It should hopefully become clearer if you try to apply your proof to the counter-example you give.

Comment: Rudin does not claim that $\overline{B} \not\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_i}$, and indeed that's false in general: for example, if we take $A_i = B$ for all $i$, then both containments hold. Rudin's statement is that the containment $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_i} \subseteq \overline{B}$ **can** be proper. I've edited your question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't we simply see which line is wrong for your counterexample $A_i =\{r_i\}$? Clearly the problem happens between the line $$\exists i\in \mathbb N \; N_r(x)\cap A_i \ne \emptyset$$ and $$\exists i \in \mathbb N\; x\in \overline A_i.$$

The problem is that in order to show $x$ is in the closure of $A_i$ we must show *every* neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A_i.$ You have forgotten to think about how the $\forall r>0$ quantifier carriers down.

We have $$ \forall r >0 \;\exists i\in\mathbb N \;(N_r(x)\cap A_i\ne 0).$$ You would need to change the order of the quantifiers to conclude $\exists i \in \mathbb N\; x\in \overline A_i,$ but that's not allowed.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

It might be instructive to look at a specific example.

Let $A_n = [0,1-{1 \over n}]$ and $B=[0,1)$. Note that $\cup_n A_n = B$ and the $A_n$ are
closed and $\overline{B} = [0,1]$.

Note that $1$ is not in the closure of any of the $A_n$.

In order to conclude that $x$ is in the closure $A_n$ you need to show that **any**
neighbourhood of $x$ contains an element of $A_n$, not just one particular neighbourhood.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you mean.