# Proof verification: If $B_{n} = \bigcup^n_{i=1} A_{i}$, prove that $\bar{B}_{n} = \bigcup^n_{i=1} \bar{A_{i}}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

(Baby Rudin, Chapter 2, Exercise 7a)

I am trying to prove:

> Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, ...$ be subsets of a metric space. If $B_{n} = \bigcup^n_{i=1} A_{i}$, prove that $\bar{B}_{n} = \bigcup^n_{i=1} \bar{A_{i}}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt:

<s>***Proof***. First, we show that $\overline{\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i} \subseteq \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$. Let $x \in \overline{\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i}$. Then, either $x \in \cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$ or $x$ is a limit point of $\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$. If $x \in \cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$, we have that $x \in A_i$ for some $i$ $\implies x \in \bar A_i$ for some $i$ $\implies x \in \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$. If $x$ is a limit point of $\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$, and if $N(x, r)$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$, then $\exists q \neq x$ such that $\color{blue}{q \in N(x, r)}$ and $q \in \cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$. Then, $q \in A_i$ for some $i \implies q \in \bar A_i$ for some $i \implies q \in \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$.
(The proof for the other direction is pretty similar.)</s>

**My question**: Can I now conclude that $\overline{\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i} \subseteq \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$? I am guessing that I cannot since I still have to show that if $x$ is a limit point of $\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i$ then $x \in \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$ (I've shown that $q \in \overline{\cup_{i =1}^{n} A_i} \implies q \in \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar A_i$ instead.) Is my guess correct? What arguments are missing from this proof still? I think will need to use the statement in blue, but I don't know how. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

- Proof Attempt 2 based on @copper.head's suggestions:

Suppose $B_{n} = \bigcup^n_{i=1} A_{i}$. First, we claim that
\begin{equation*}
        \overline{A_1 \cup A_2} \subset \overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2}
    \end{equation*}
Let $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$. Then, $x \in A_1 \textrm{ or } x \in A_2 \implies x \in \overline{A_1} \textrm{ or } x \in \overline{A_2} \implies x \in \overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2}$. Thus, $A_1 \cup A_2 \subset \bar{A_1} \cup \bar{A_2}$. (Just to be clear, it was mentioned in Chapter 1 that Rudin uses $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ interchangeably.)  Note that since $\bar{A_1}$ and $\bar{A_2}$ are closed, $\bar{A_1} \cup \bar{A_2}$ is closed as well. Then, $\overline{A_1 \cup A_2} \subset \bar{A_1} \cup \bar{A_2}$.

Continuing inductively, suppose $\overline{\cup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i} \subset \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar{A_i}$. Let $y \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n+1} A_i$. Then, $y \in A_i$ for some $i \in [1, n+1]$.

**My question**: How can I prove that $\cup_{i = 1}^{n+1}A_i  \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n+1} \overline{A_i}$ in a way that utilizes the induction hypothesis (I know how to prove the same without using the induction hypothesis)? Then, $\overline{\cup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i}  \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} \overline{A_i}$ will follow immediately.

Please know that I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903464/baby-rudin-exercise-2-7) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448459/rudin-exercise-2-7-union-of-subsets-of-a-metric-space-and-closure-thereof) but I am asking for specific ways of completing my proof.

Comment: You are missing something. It does not hold for $n=\infty$, note that $\cup_n [-1+{1 \over n},1-{1 \over n}] = (-1,1)$. The exercise is for **finite** $n$. Also, you need only show that $A_1 \cup A_2$ is closed and then use induction.

Comment: @copper.hat Using $\infty$ instead of $n$ was a typo on my part; it's fixed now, thanks! Is there a method that will allow me to complete my proof or would that lead to over-complications?

Comment: It depends on how you define closed. Also, I really would work with $A,B$ rather than $n$ of them, just to avoid notational clutter.

Comment: @copper.hat Rudin defines a closed set as: "$E$ is closed if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$", which is probably the standard definition. Just to be clear, are you suggesting that I abandon my current approach and develop a proof using the induction methodology you've suggested?

Comment: Not suggesting abandonment, just simplification. If you prove that $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ then it is easy to see that if follows for a fnite number since $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup A_3$, etc.

Comment: How does Rudin define the closure? (It does not matter here, but a more general definition of closed is that the complement is open.)

Comment: Note that this is just my opinion, different folks will have different suggestions. Personally I prefer simple because it is easier to follow and I am less likely to make mistakes. And people differ on what simple means :-).

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying to derail you, just making suggestions. But could you clarify how you define closure?

Comment: Rudin's definition of closure (denoted by $\bar E$):  $\bar E = E \cup E'$ where $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$. And you did not derail me, I like exploring various ways of proving things :)

Comment: Thanks, so you need to show that $A \cup B \cup (A \cup B)' = A \cup B \cup A' \cup B' $.

Comment: You might find this useful https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550920/27978.

Comment: @copper.hat I've added a second proof based on your suggestion. Can you please review it? Also, can you please suggest how the induction step can be completed?

Comment: You have just shown one direction, you also need to show that $\overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2} \subset \overline{A_1 \cup A_2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat I will add the other direction in a few minutes (still working on it) but I am having trouble completing the first direction as well (as I also specify in my question)

Comment: First finish the other direction. Then the inductive step is simpler. First finish the other direction. Then the inductive step is simpler. If $\overline{\cup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i} = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} \bar{A_i}$,  then$\overline{\cup_{i = 1}^{n+1}A_i} = \overline{A_{n+1}} \cup \overline{\cup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i} = \overline{A_{n+1}} \cup {\cup_{i = 1}^{n}\overline{A_i}} = \cup_{i = 1}^{n+1}\overline{A_i}$.

Comment: But, to answer your question, what you have looks good. If I was to prove it, I would use Oliver's method below.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to look at this.

Notice $\bigcup^n_{k=1}A_k \subset \bigcup^n_{k=1}\overline{A_k}$ and so

$$\overline{\bigcup^n_{k=1}A_k } \subset \bigcup^n_{k=1}\overline{A_k}$$
Here we have used the fact that $A\subset B$ implies that $\overline{A}\subset\overline{B}$ and also that $\overline{B}=B$ when $B$ is closed.

On the other hand,
$$\overline{A_k}\subset\overline{\bigcup^n_{k=1}A_k}$$
Thus
$$\bigcup^n_{k=1}\overline{A_k}\subset\overline{\bigcup^n_{k=1}A_k}$$